# rsync adding executable flag when syncing over network

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

I’m running rsync to synchronize two Debian machines. Both the source and the destination file systems are ext4.

Naturally I want to preserve the permissions so I’m running the command with the recommended -a flag. Still I get that most of the files (I say most since I cannot say with certainty that this is always the case) become executables (I.e. get the executable flag set).

If I try the same command locally on one machine it seems to work.

Can someone help me understand what I’m doing wrong? I’ve searched the net but couldn’t find anything helpful. The closest indicated that the file system could be the problem. However that was for FAT. Is this also a problem for ext4?

The command I’m running has the following structure:

```
rsync -a user@ip_address:/source_folder destination_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

The -a flag should be right, but...

You are copying from remote to local, meaning that the files will locally be written by rsync in combination with your own UMASK and already existing permissions on the local folder-tree that you use as target.

I guess that is causing the x bit to be added.

Comment: That is only true if `-p` is not set: "When this option is off, permissions are set as follows: New  files  get  their "normal" permission bits set to the source file's permissions masked with the receiving directory's default permissions (either the receiving process's umask, or
                     the permissions specified via the destination directory's default ACL), and their special permission bits disabled except in the case where a new directory inherits a setgid  bit  from
                     its parent directory."

Comment: @mashuptwice That is normally the case, but there are some (very rare) cases were the local permissions/ACLs still combine with the -p flag (which is implicit in -a). That usually requires some very funky ACL stuff being present on the target filesystem though.